# Could not list contents of ../node_modules/.bin/npm'. Android publishing

Tags: android, react-native, publishing

I am trying to publish my first android app,but when I type
./gradlew installRelease
I get the following error

Could not list contents of ../node_modules/.bin/npm'

Has anyone encountered this error or have any idea of how to solve it?  Thanks

Just for interest sake, if I cd in my terminal I can get to .bin
but when I try open npm or cd npm it says it can't find it, however if I type ls in .bin then npm is listed. Not sure if this is relevant

Comment: https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/10849

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay I worked it out, I deleted npm and it then worked fine.  No idea why